# Kotlin - Class not recognized

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, import, bazel

I have two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB` inside two projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` respectively. The packages they are in have the exact same name and path, i.e., ClassA is in `ProjectA/src/main/java/com/xyz/pqr/uvw`, while ClassB is in `ProjectB/src/main/java/com/xyz/pqr/uvw`.
I'm trying to use create an object of ClassB inside ClassA but when I build the project, the compiler gives me `error: unresolved reference: ClassB`.
I noticed that ClassB is not imported by the IDE either. I tried manually importing it but the IDE treats it as an unused import.

How do I fix this problem?

For reference, the code structure is as below. ClassA is written in Kotlin and ClassB is written in Java. (Also, ClassB is actually an interface)

```
package com.xyz.pqr.uvw

@Component
class ClassA(
    val classB: ClassB
): InterfaceC {
    fun useClassB() {
        return classB.calc()
    }
}
```

```
package com.xyz.pqr.uvw

public interface ClassB {
    String calc() {...}
}
```

Comment: What build tool do you use and how are the two projects linked together?

Comment: I use bazel. The two projects are subdirectories of a bigger project in a monorepo.
Structured this way: monorepo/projects/services/teamname/projectA and monorepo/projects/services/teamname/projectB

Comment: Thats wrong code implementation. You can find it here in given [examples](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin).  You should pass them in two different build files of two different packages.